# How to combine two almost similar RxJava methods?

Tags: refactoring, rx-java, rx-android

I have two RxJava-style methods:

```
void requestFirst() {
    Observable
        .combineLatest(
            api.requestAPI1(),
            api.requestAPI2(),
            (result1, result2) -> result1)
        .map(result -> processResult(result))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe(etc1())
        .doOnSubscribe(etc2())
        .subscribe(
            result -> onComplete(result),
            e -> onError(e));
}

void requestNext() {
    api.requestAPI1()
        .map(result -> processResult(result))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe(etc1())
        .doOnSubscribe(etc2())
        .subscribe(
            result -> onComplete(result),
            e -> onError(e));
}
```

Two methods are almost same except combineLatest,
and I want to merge it for refactoring. 
So I write following code:

```
void request(boolean isFirst) {
    Observable
        .combineLatest(
            api.requestAPI1(),
            (isFirst) ? api.requestAPI2() : Observable.empty(),
            (result1, result2) -> result1)
        .map(result -> processResult(result))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe(etc1())
        .doOnSubscribe(etc2())
        .subscribe(
            result -> onComplete(result),
            e -> onError(e));
}
```

But I think that second parameter of combineLatest method isn't Rx's style.
How can I merge this two similar methods by Rx's style?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use operator `.merge()`

```
final Observable tworequestsObservable = Observable
    .combineLatest(
        api.requestAPI1(),
        api.requestAPI2(),
        (result1, result2) -> result1)

void requestNext() {
    Observable.merge(api.requestAPI1(), tworequestsObservable)
        .map(result -> processResult(result))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe(etc1())
        .doOnSubscribe(etc2())
        .subscribe(
            result -> onComplete(result),
            e -> onError(e));
}
```

And you can add `.distinctUntilChange()` just after `merge` to avoid double processing `api.requestAPI1()` result.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new method:

```
void processResults(Observable<Source> dataSource) {
    results.map(result -> processResult(result))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe(etc1())
    .doOnSubscribe(etc2())
    .subscribe(
        result -> onComplete(result),
        e -> onError(e));
}
```

and use it as:

```
void requestNext() {
  processResults(api.requestAPI1());
}
```

Comment: Strange solution! First of all : it looks like not according to "Rx Patterns". Secondary: in such case how to handle subscription, unsubscribe when it's needed etc.?